# how to add a JSON file data into Cloud Firestore + Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

i have a huge JSON data with keys and value pairs. like the below code i have so many data in my file

```
 {
     "Tamil Nadu": {
         "Chennai ": {
            "Anna Nagar": "600040 ",
            "New Avadi road": "600010 "
        },
        "Tiruvallur ": {
         "Ambattur": "600053 ",
           "Mogappair": "600037 "
        
    }

     },
    "Andhra Pradesh": {
        "Anantapur ": {
            "A Narayanapuram": "515001 ",
            "Achampalle": "515621 "
        },
        "Chittoor ": {
             "Agraharam": "517640 ",
             "Badikayalapalle": "517370 "
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

how can i add those huge data into cloud firestore database as one of a collection and corressponding documents.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure about which Firebase database you are using, since you tagged your question with `firebase-realtime-database` and `google-cloud-firestore` and you mentioned "Cloud Firestore" in the title. So let's share some solutions for the two database systems offered by Firebase.

## For Firestore

The easiest approach IMHO is to use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) from your computer: "The Admin SDK is a set of server libraries that lets you interact with Firebase from privileged environments".

You can create a JS file with, for example, the following content and save it on your computer. After having installed Node.js, you can then run it with the following command: `node <filename>`.

```
#!/usr/bin/node
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert("....json")
});

const data = {
    "Tamil Nadu": {
        "Chennai ": {
            "Anna Nagar": "600040 ",
            "New Avadi road": "600010 "
        },
        "Tiruvallur ": {
            "Ambattur": "600053 ",
            "Mogappair": "600037 "
        }
    },
    "Andhra Pradesh": {
        "Anantapur ": {
            "A Narayanapuram": "515001 ",
            "Achampalle": "515621 "
        },
        "Chittoor ": {
            "Agraharam": "517640 ",
            "Badikayalapalle": "517370 "
        }
    }
}

const promises = [];
const dataArray = Object.entries(data);

dataArray.forEach(d => {
     promises.push(admin.firestore().collection('abc').doc(d[0]).set(d[1]));
})
Promise.all(promises);
```

You may need to adapt the parsing of the JSON object to cope with the desired Firestore data stucture.

---

For the authentication, you can [initialize the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk) with the credentials for a service account with the Editor role on your Firebase project with

```
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert("....json")
});
```

To get the json file shown right above, go to the Firebase console, click on the gear in the top-left corner, select the "Service accounts" tab and click on the blue "Generate new private key" button at the bottom.

[image]

## For the Realtime Database

Here are three possible approaches:

##### 1/ Use the CLI

The [CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#rtdb-commands) offers several commands to push, update or set data. See also this Firebase [blog article](https://firebase.blog/posts/2017/12/read-and-write-your-realtime-database).

##### 2/ Use the JSON Import button

In the console you'll found a button as shown below. You can choose under which node you want to upload data but be aware that all existing data at this node will be overwritten"

[image]

##### 3/ Use the Admin SDK

As we did with Firestore you can use the Admin SDK for the Realtime Database. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/node
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert("....json") // See below
});

const data = {
    "Tamil Nadu": {
        "Chennai ": {
            "Anna Nagar": "600040 ",
            "New Avadi road": "600010 "
        },
        "Tiruvallur ": {
            "Ambattur": "600053 ",
            "Mogappair": "600037 "
        }
    },
    "Andhra Pradesh": {
        "Anantapur ": {
            "A Narayanapuram": "515001 ",
            "Achampalle": "515621 "
        },
        "Chittoor ": {
            "Agraharam": "517640 ",
            "Badikayalapalle": "517370 "
        }
    }
}

admin.database().ref('....').set(data);
```

---

Note that you may encounter an error from the Database if you try to upload in one shot a very large set of data. You'll then need to upload by chunks.